# IBAForms: how to create a IBATextFormField which is not editable?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using IBAForms to collection user input, there is a case where some of the fields are editable and others are not, is there any immutable or disabled IBAFormField, or any other way to implement this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use IBAReadonlyFormField